# Optimize: convert has no method matching

Tags: optimization, julia

This is the first time that I write Julia code. I am writing a function to calculate the Likelihood for linear mixed models with specific var-cov matrix for random terms. Then I want to use `optimize` from the `Optim` package to get the variance of random terms. However, I cannot make it work.

The code and the example data are here: https://github.com/daijiang/pglmm.jl/blob/master/pglmm.jl

The code runs well in R but very slow. So I am trying to convert it into Julia. I have very little idea why this error happened.

> MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64},
>   ::Array{Float64,1}) This may have arisen from a call to the
>   constructor Float64(...), since type constructors fall back to convert
>   methods. Closest candidates are:   call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
>   convert(::Type{Float64}, !Matched::Int8)   convert(::Type{Float64},
>   !Matched::Int16)   ...  in nelder_mead at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Optim/src/nelder_mead.jl:74  in optimize at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Optim/src/optimize.jl:482  in include_string at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/CodeTools/src/eval.jl:28  in include_string at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/CodeTools/src/eval.jl:32  [inlined code] from
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:39  in anonymous at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:62  in withpath at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Requires/src/require.jl:37  in withpath at
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:53  [inlined code] from
>   /home/dli/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:61  in anonymous at task.jl:58

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: pglmm_LL() should returns a `Number` but it gets a `Vector`. so `optimize` fails, the code has some disadvantages, that make it hard to **maintenance** and **slow**, 1-over usage of globals, 2-lack of explicit type definitions.

Comment: @RezaAfzalan thanks! Now I finally get it to work by using `return(LL[1,1])`, which is odd by the way... I will first make the code work and then to profile them. Thanks again for your help.